# Use and meaning of "that+sub+should....."in a sentence

Tags: modal-verbs, interpretation

It’s strange that you **should** say that.

I think this sentence express "your saying of that is strange".

I'm not sure about the interpretation, someone give your valuable time to answer my question.

Comment: See [SHOULD to express surprise](https://www.grammaring.com/the-modal-should-to-express-surprise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It’s strange that you should say that.

Yes, this sentence expresses "your saying of that is strange".

Examples of that-clauses used in this manner can be found [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses).

> Adjective + that-clause
> We use be + adjective + that-clause to express opinions and feelings.

> It’s important (that) we look at the problem in more detail.